# C# aync await - Gui Freezing When out of focus

Tags: winforms, sorting, async-await

I decided recently to take a look at the new async/await features of C#5.  For demonstration purposes I programmed a Windows Forms application that allows the user to take an array of integers and sort them using the sort-routine of their choice.  Along with the program I provide five test .dat files, each of which contains un-sorted data starting at 32,000 integers and doubling in size per each subsequent file.  The program reads the data from the files into an int array ready for sort.

The problem I have is that the GUI freezes up and becomes totally unresponsive.  However, it will only freeze if the GUI itself is placed in the background.  i.e., I can’t see it because I may be busy browsing the internet etc.  It may not be an instant freeze.  Sometimes I may return it back into focus and it will still be working, but eventually it will fail.  If I leave the program in focus at all times, the GUI will remain completely responsive.  I can drag it across the screen.  I can minimise and maximise it. A marquee style progress bar animates and I can carry on clicking buttons etc, before a results form displays the elapsed sort time.

Now I would add that I do not believe this to be an issue with the sort algorithm itself.  My reasoning being that it works fine when the GUI is left in focus.  I also have a full suite of unit tests verifying that each algorithm works as it should.  Elapsed time would seem to be an issue as quicker algorithms such as Heap or Quick sort can handle very large data sets without a resulting freeze.  Finally, I have tried catching an exception both at the form level, where I await the Task, and from within the task itself, and yet no exception appears to be thrown.

Having only just looked at async/await over the last two days, I am by no means an expert but my initial thoughts are it may be related to the GUI repainting when bought back into focus.  Can anybody help?  Below are sections of the code to assist:-

Example SelectionSort routine:-

```
public SelectionSort(IStopwatch stopwatch) : base(stopwatch){}

    public override async Task<int[]> SortAsync(int[] data, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        OnStarted();           
        Stopwatch.Start();

        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int i, j;
                int min, temp;

                for (i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;

                    min = i;
                    for (j = i + 1; j < data.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (data[j] < data[min])
                            min = j;
                    }
                    temp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[min];
                    data[min] = temp;
                }
            }, cancelToken);

        Stopwatch.Stop();

        OnCompleted(new SortCompleteEventArgs(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, data.Length, cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested));

        return data;
    }
```

The Sorter Context to handle each sort routine (Strategy Pattern):-

```
public class SorterContext
{
    private readonly SortRoutine _sortRoutine;

    public SorterContext(SortRoutine sortRoutine)
    {
        _sortRoutine = sortRoutine;
    }

    public async Task<int[]> Sort(int[] dataToSort, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(dataToSort == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataToSort");

        if(dataToSort.Length == 1) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dataToSort");

        int[] result = await _sortRoutine.SortAsync(dataToSort, cancellationToken);

        return result;
    }
```

The call from within the Windows Form Click event handler:-

```
private async void StartSorting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_lBoxSelectedFiles.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select data to sort");
            return;
        }

        _btnCancelSort.Enabled = true;

        if (_comboBxAlgorithm.SelectedValue.Equals("SelectSort"))
        {
            var selectSort = new SelectSort(new SortStopwatch());
            selectSort.Completed += DisplaySortResults;
            _sorter = new SorterContext(selectSort);

            StartProgressBar();

             await _sorter.Sort(_dataToSort, _cancelTokenSrcWrapper.Token);   
        }
```

Comment: A more fitting demo of `async` would be a naturally-asynchronous operation, i.e., web requests to your localhost server that just sleeps for each request. `async` wasn't primarily designed for CPU-intensive work, though you *can* use `Task.Run` as you have here. That said, I don't see anything in your posted code that should cause UI responsiveness issues.

Comment: Very strange this.  It appears to be down to the OnCompleted event raised in the Sort Algorithm.  If that is commented out no problems, no freezes though obviously the results screen will not now diplay.  Works fine again with the gui in focus.  Fails whilst it is in the background.  Almost stumped but still working on it.  Have a feeling it may be a "kick myself" moment.

Comment: One thing to check: ensure the results aren't each a UI element (e.g., 100,000 list items will not go over well).

Comment: Hi Stephen.  Thanks for the input.  The results data is not used in that manner.  I will edit my post because it actually freezes now on  smaller sort numbers.  Mind you I say 'now' but I suspect it has always been doing that and I missed it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be nothing wrong with the async code.  When the OnComplete event is raised after the sort, the handler in the main form instantiates a new results form and displays it.  This was failing when the form was out of focus.  I am looking into why this is the case and if it is a deliberate framework design decision.  Anyhow, I simply called method Activate() from within the handler. This brings the application into focus and I then instantiated the new form and it works fine.  It will do for me at least anyhow.  e.g:-

```
private void DisplaySortResults(object sender, SortCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Activate();

        _btnCancelSort.Enabled = false;
        _progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;

        var sortResults = new SortResults();

        sortResults.BuildResults(e);
        sortResults.SetCompletedValues(e);
        sortResults.ShowDialog();
    }
```